# Is the minimum singular value (amplitude) of $\boldsymbol{AB}$ bounded by the counterparts of $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, singular-values

Consider two complex matrices $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{M\times N}$ and $\boldsymbol{B} \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times Q}$. Is the minimum singular value's amplitude of $\boldsymbol{AB}$ bounded by the minimum singular value amplitudes of $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$? That is,

does
$$
|\sigma_{min}(\boldsymbol{AB})| \leq \min \{|\sigma_{min}(\boldsymbol{A})|,|\sigma_{min}(\boldsymbol{B})|\}
$$
hold?

Comment: Try with $A= \operatorname{diag}(1, {1 \over 2}), B= \operatorname{diag}({1 \over 2},1)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Wow thanks, then what if $\min\{|\sigma_{min}(\boldsymbol{A})|,|\sigma_{min}(\boldsymbol{B})|\}$? Is $|\sigma_{min}(\boldsymbol{AB})|$ bounded by this?

Comment: @copper.hat Can I intuitively believe that, since the rank of $\boldsymbol{AB}$ will be lower than $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$, then $|\sigma_{min}(\boldsymbol{AB})|$ can not be greater than $|\sigma_{min}(\boldsymbol{A})|$ and $|\sigma_{min}(\boldsymbol{B})|$?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't even work for scalar matrices.

An inequality of this type should be homogenous, of the correct degree.

The inequality you do have is
$$\sigma_{\min}(A B) \ge \sigma_{\min}(A) \cdot \sigma_{\min}(B)$$

Comment: What if when both $|\sigma_{min}(\boldsymbol{A})|$ and $|\sigma_{min}(\boldsymbol{B})|$ lower than 1? Is the original proposition valid at this time? And can you give me some hint to prove your inequality?